# Common Lisp: call a function A with a function fn and A returns a lambda function that invokes fn

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The following function outputs `Hello, world`

```
(defun helloworld ()
    (format t "Hello, world"))
```

Function `A` calls function `B`, passing it the `helloworld` function:

```
(defun A ()
    ((B #'helloworld)))
```

Function `B` returns a lambda function, which invokes the function passed to `B`:

```
(defun B (fn)
    (#'lambda () 
        (funcall fn)))
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. Presumably I am doing something incorrect in function `A`. How do I get this to work please?

Comment: You should be getting an error for `(defun A ()
    ((B #'helloworld)))`.  `((B #'helloworld))` isn't legal in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `funcall` in function A since the return value of function B is not in the function namespace:

```
? (defun helloworld ()
    (format t "Hello, world"))
HELLOWORLD

? (defun B (fn)
    (lambda () (funcall fn)))
B

? (defun A ()
    (funcall (B #'helloworld)))    
A

? (a)
Hello, world
NIL
?
```

[Here](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/functions.html) is some more reading on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to understand it in an wrong way. The first item of every list form is not going to be evaluated in the same way as the rest of the items. The first expression of list forms must be either a symbol (as in `(+ 1 2)`), or a lambda expression (as in `((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)`). That means, that you cannot use anything like `((B #'helloworld))`. Instead you should use the function object, returned from `(B #'helloworld)`, as an argument, passed to `funcall`.